# Phonegap/Cordova - download jpg to local FS on Windows Phone 8/8.1

Tags: android, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I have been trying to download an image from an url to local file system using cordova 3.8 on Windows Phone.

I want to store pictures and be able to use them in the HTML view.

I am using the file transfer and the file system plugins :

- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer
- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html

I have been playing around with both, but without success. I think the problem comes from the target file URI, as I have not found any way of getting the download folder path.

I can easily read and write text files using the examples in the cordova-file plugin's documentation, but I do not find anything on how to get the directory's path in order to pass it to the file transfer plugin.

Any idea ? I am testing on WP8.

Comment: Hi i am having exactly the same problem, did you find a solution?, may you want share? i have this code and it work´s fine on android, but not on windows phone: http://plnkr.co/edit/SIX6dudoOXc713JWycA3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own plugin(I can explain how if needed) and use [MediaLibrary.SavePicture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604988.aspx) method. Put this in your plugin class:

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public void SavePicture(string options)
{
    string[] optString = getOptionStrings(options);
    string url = optString[0];
    string callbackId = optString[1];

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback((result) =>
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
            byte[] content = ReadFully(response.GetResponseStream());

            MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary();

            lib.SavePicture("Test Picture", content);
            DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK), callbackId);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, e), callbackId);
        }
    }), null);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
cordova.exec(function (result) {
    // success             
}, function (e) {
    // error
}, 'YourPluginClass', 'SavePicture', [yourUrl]);
```

NOTE: You must have ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO capability checked in the manifest.